# How to pass data to stateful widget

Tags: flutter, dart

When i try to pass data to a stateful widget i get this error :

A [State] object's configuration is the corresponding [StatefulWidget] instance. This property is initialized by the framework before calling [initState].
Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

### Basically i'm trying to pass data from detail.dart to about.dart

detail.dart :

```
class PokemonDetail extends StatefulWidget {
PokemonDetail({this.pokemon});

@override
_PokemonDetailState createState() => _PokemonDetailState();
}

class _PokemonDetailState extends State<PokemonDetail> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
final List<TabData> _tabs = [
TabData("About", PokemonAbout(pokemon: widget.pokemon)),
....];


@override
_PokemonAboutState createState() => _PokemonAboutState();
}


Widget _buildTabContent() {
return Expanded(
  child: TabBarView(
    children: _tabs.map((tab) => tab.child).toList(),
  ),
);
}
```

about.dart :

```
class PokemonAbout extends StatefulWidget {
final Pokemon pokemon;

const PokemonAbout({this.pokemon, key}) : super(key: key);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'widget.pokemon' cannot be used in class-level field initialization. Try moving tabs declaration inside the initState:

```
class _PokemonDetailState extends State<PokemonDetail> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin{
List<TabData> _tabs = [];

@override
void initState(){
   super.initState();
   _tabs = [ TabData("About", PokemonAbout(pokemon: widget.pokemon)), ....];
}
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This line `_PokemonAboutState createState() => _PokemonAboutState();` should not be called inside the `State` class. It is already defined in the `StatefulWidget` class. Try removing it and see what happens.

Comment: Sorry about that typo, that line is in about.dart.